# related to .net - Parser Error Message: Could not load type

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am running the .net application but i got this error

"Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication10.Global'.

Source Error:

> Line 1:  <%@ Application
>   Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
>   Inherits="WebApplication10.Global"
>   Language="C#" %>
>
> Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 "

I dont know why its was giving this error

Comment: Can you say whether this is a Web Forms app or an MVC app? also which version of the .NET Framework are you working with?

Comment: Can you post the relevant content of your Global.asax file?

Comment: Can you say whether this is a new solution your working on or a legacy app?

Comment: Was this first built on your machine or a different machine? If on a different machine, did the person who asked you to work on the project provide you with all of the necessary assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

`WebApplication10` needs to be included as a reference in your app.

Here is some info from Microsoft Support
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306155

I'm not familiar with the namespace `WebApplication10` so it's either

1. A custom assembly
2. An assembly I've never heard of / can't find
3. The wrong assembly reference.
4. A project within your solution that needs to be built

Your resolution steps would be to

1. "Build" your solution (if the problem is from #4 above)
2. open up the search on your machine and look for `WebApplication10` on your computer. If you find it, add it as an assembly reference, if you don't find it, remove it and see what happens. (if the problem is #1, #2 or #3 above)

Here's what the first line in my Global.asax file looks like

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
```

Now I'm not a C# guy, so I've gone to a random Codeplex web application and looked at what's at the top of a C# Global.asax file, and this is what I see.

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
```

So I'm thinking you should start there.

---

### Edit

Upon further digging, it appears as though `WebApplication10` **might** have something to do with the .NET 1.0 framework. Do you have .NET 1 installed on your machine? Are you working with a legacy app or is this a brand new project you're working on?

Comment: I dont know how to add this one would you pls tell

Comment: I've edited my answer. As I said, I was still searching for you.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication10
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup

        }

        void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this is my global.asax file starting

Comment: code formatting in comments sucks. Please edit your original question and use the code formatting feature in there to post your Global.asax file.

Comment: namespace WebApplication10
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }

        void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          

        }

        void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }

        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }

Comment: ****void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

Comment: this is asp.net application i am working with .net 4.0 version

Comment: would any one tell the solution for this problem

Comment: As I said. you have to edit your question to post the code with a proper format. Give us more details. I have answered your vague question as best I can. And when you post your code in a comment field, it's nearly impossible to read.